# How can i handle my Looper in an OnClick method to run a function with delay?

Tags: android, handler, looper

I would like to be able to run my specific method in background through a looper in an on click event, is this the right way to do this?

```
myThread = new LooperThread();
    myThread.start();
    upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myThread.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //my methods
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And my Looper Class:

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
    Handler handler;
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler();
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

If it is,
the problem is that in this way, i don't understand why the system don't recognize "handler" while i typing: "myThread.handler.post.." and run the methods.

Otherwise, can you help me on making this?

I am sorry if i made mistakes while making the question, but it's my first time here :)``

Comment: Technically it's correct. But for this you'd also have [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) to create a thread with a looper you can use to create a handler with.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not clear for me how HandlerThread works exactly. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

> I would like to be able to run my specific method in background through a looper in an on click event, is this the right way to do this?

Your code works, but I couldn't say it's the *right* way to do it. Like @tynn mentioned, a `HandlerThread` might be a better option.

> If it is, the problem is that in this way, i don't understand why the system don't recognize "handler" while i typing: "myThread.handler.post.." and run the methods.
>
> Otherwise, can you help me on making this?

If I understood your problem, it's an access issue. Your handler seems unaccessible since it's declared as package-private. You could make your handler visible this way:

```java
// Should this class be public or package-private?
public class LooperThread extends Thread {

    private Handler handler;

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And you will be able to reference the handler like this:

```
myThread.getHandler().post(...);
```

#### UPDATE

You can delay a `Runnable` execution this way:

```java
// Delay execution of a Runnable task by 5000 milliseconds.
myThread.getHandler().postDelayed(myDelayedRunnable, 5000);
```

Comment: Ok i solved the "handler" problem.
I declared "Thread myThread" instead of "LooperThread myThread", now it works :)

Thank you for the answer, you have been very helpfull :)